# Copy photos with terminal

Tags: kubuntu

I'm going to copy all the photos on my computer to a flash drive.I just want the photos to be copied.I have many folders and I want to copy photos from all folders automatically. I do not know how to do this with the terminal. Thankful

Comment: Start by reading `man cp`. Then [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391469/edit) your Question above to provide a specific example of the problem if you want specific help.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391469/edit) and indicate the location of your photos. Are they located in `/home/$USER/Pictures` or some other location?